# MySQL errors when trying to start it

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-18.04

i have been stuck on this for days now. When i run `service mysql start`
 it returns this:

```
matthew@matthewserver:~$ service mysql start
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'mysql.service'.
Authenticating as: matthew tranmer (matthew)
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When i run `journalctl -xe`:

```
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Oct 02 16:32:27 matthewserver mysql-systemd-start[31599]: ERROR: Unable to start MySQL server:
Oct 02 16:32:27 matthewserver mysql-systemd-start[31599]: 2018-10-02T16:32:27.849609Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'key_buffer=16M'
Oct 02 16:32:27 matthewserver mysql-systemd-start[31599]: 2018-10-02T16:32:27.857580Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Oct 02 16:32:27 matthewserver mysql-systemd-start[31599]: Please take a look at https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/MySQL/FAQ for tips on fixing common upgrade issues.
Oct 02 16:32:27 matthewserver mysql-systemd-start[31599]: Once the problem is resolved, restart the service.
Oct 02 16:32:27 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 02 16:32:27 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 02 16:32:27 matthewserver systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
Oct 02 16:32:28 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 02 16:32:28 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit mysql.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Oct 02 16:32:28 matthewserver systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Oct 02 16:32:28 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 02 16:32:28 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 02 16:32:28 matthewserver systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
```

and when i run `systemctl status mysql.service` i get:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-10-02 16:32:28 UTC; 2min 33s ago
  Process: 28760 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 31599 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 02 16:32:27 matthewserver mysql-systemd-start[31599]: Once the problem is resolved, restart the service.
Oct 02 16:32:27 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 02 16:32:27 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 02 16:32:27 matthewserver systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Oct 02 16:32:28 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Oct 02 16:32:28 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Oct 02 16:32:28 matthewserver systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Oct 02 16:32:28 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 02 16:32:28 matthewserver systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 02 16:32:28 matthewserver systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

This happens when i run `sudo mysql`

```
matthew@matthewserver:~$ sudo mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I do not know what to do to get it working, this is kinda a last resort.

Answer (score 3):

There is a line in the output of journalctl:

> 2018-10-02T16:32:27.849609Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'key_buffer=16M'

This system variable doesn't exist. Maybe the variable that you are trying to set is the `key_buffer_size`. In the `my.cnf` file, which is usually located in `/etc`, remove the `key_buffer` entry and add the one below:

> key_buffer_size = 16M

Comment: can i get a very basic my.cnf example file with just the bind address?

Comment: @matthewtranmer,  you can create one yourself. The important thing is to add groups, in the MySQL server case, a `[mysqld]` group. Then, you declare the system variables below the group created. 
The docs have a good explanation about that. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

Comment: i have managed to fix the start error but i still cant do `sudo mysql ` it gives me  `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in mysqld configuration:

> Oct 02 16:32:27 matthewserver mysql-systemd-start[31599]: 2018-10-02T16:32:27.849609Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'key_buffer=16M'

You should use `key_buffer_size=16M`, not `key_buffer=16M`

Comment: i have changed the my.cnf to:`# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/

[mysqld]
bind-address        = 172.0.0.1
# skip-networking`

Comment: and i still get the same error

Comment: You have a typo in bind-address, change it to `bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Do `!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/` line is uncommented in your my.cnf? If yes then you should check /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/ directory for additional configuration files - all of them are being loaded into my.cnf and can affect mysqld configuration.

Comment: Check port=xxx and socket=xxx options in all your configuration files. They should be the same for [mysqld] section and [client] and [mysql] sections when you are connecting from mysql to mysqld server running at localhost.